# AspectJ load-time weaving configuration without XML

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Is it possible to configure AspectJ LTW solely in Java? I don't want to deal with XML, and I was wondering if I can do without it. I searched through AspectJ website, and I found only the XML way.

I am planning to use it with Spring, hopefully without any strange consequences(had enough problems already:)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up Spring to use [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) mostly using Spring annotations. But you do need `META-INF/aop.xml` because this is an AspectJ LTW requirement, it does not come from Spring. AspectJ is an independent technology which does not need Spring, Spring only supports it being used in its own context.

If you don't like XML for whatever reason - done right there is no problem and you only need to touch the file once - use CTW (compile-time weaving), e.g. via [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/).